# Cannot resolve method for SparseArray<TextBlock>

Tags: android, textblock, android-sparsearray

this is a piece of a script that has to recognize a text from the camera through `TextRecognizer` and then search a certain word inside the text. If the word is present, the system has to save in `String found` the word after.

The problem is that I have this two errors:

```
Cannot resolve method 'contains(java.lang.String)'
Cannot resolve method 'getValue(int)'
```

How can I solve this errors? I haven't found any similar method for `SparseArray<TextBlock>`.

```
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

  String search = "palabra";
  final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems(); //is the detection of textRecognizer of the camera

  for (int i=0; i<items.size(); ++i) 
  {
    if(items.get(i).contains(search)) 
    {
       String found = items.getValue(i+1);
       Log.i("current lines ", found);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the [`SparseArray` documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html).

As you can see, there is no `getValue()` method on SparseArray, so calling `getValue(int)` on a `SparseArray` like your `items` variable is not valid.

Similarly, [`TextBlock`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock) doesn't have a `contains(String)` method. Calling `items.get(i)` will return a `TextBlock`, so attempting to call `contains(String)` on a `TextBlock` is similarly invalid.

Based on what I see in your code, I'm guessing you are looking for something more like this, which calls `String`'s `contains()` method:

```
for (int i=0; i<items.size(); ++i) {]
    TextBlock text = items.get(i)

    // Get the TextBlock's value as a String
    String value = text.getValue()

    // Check if this text block contains the search string
    if(value.contains(search)) {
        String found = items.getValue(i+1);
        Log.i("Found search string " + search + " in block " + value);
    }
}
```